# Enterprise web app using Dart or Node.js

Tags: node.js, dart

I am very confuse about web technologies. I invested a lot of time to learn Javascript and Node.js, and I really enjoy to code in javascript. Few days ago, I discovered Google Dart.

The article about Google Dart, that I had read, sounds promising, about the future of Dart.

My question is, should I decide for Dart or Node.js?

I plan to develop enterprise web applications. I have read that Javascript is not as highly scalable as Dart, it's that true?

Will firefox and co implements Dart VM too? I know that it is possible to convert Dart code into Javascript code, but this does not make sense for me.

Comment: Probably you should clear your question a bit otherwise it might be closed as "too broad" or "primarily opinion-based".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"should I decide for Dart or node.js" - This question makes no sense. Node just interprets javascript code and runs it but also has something like modules.

Dart ist a language that was developed after JavaScript and brings a lot of new features. If you enjoy coding javascript code, why would you want to learn Dart then? ;)

I personally never liked JavaScript because there was no real OOP. With Dart there is OOP and much more!

The future will show if Dart will be adapted by firefox, IE etc - but as far as I know Microsoft tries to adopt a replacement for javascript as well - the future will tell. Right now Dart looks really strong and makes a lot of sense to me.

Though Dart can also run on server side and has a lot of cool features and there are lots of packages on http://pub.dartlang.org

In the end you still have no disadvantages from coding in Dart because it is much better and sometimes js code compiled from Dart might be even faster then directly coding in javascript. So you have decide yourself what you like more. As a passionate programmer I'd always prefer Dart over javascript - no doubt here!

Answer (score 4):

For enterprise applications Dart is a perfect fit.

I can't understand why compiling Dart to JavaScript doesn't make sense to you.
You still get most of the advantages but just not the execution speed of pure Dart. 
The browsers that support Dart directly will start and execute Dart code much faster.

The runtime performance of Dart converted to JS is about the same like code written in JavaScript in the first time but you get still the superior development experience with type annotations, static analysis, autocompletion, packages, libraries, classes, ...

The bigger the app gets the more important are these advantages.

A disadvantage of Dart is, that there are still not so many libraries and GUI widgets available as for JavaScript but there is a lot going on here (take a look at https://pub.dartlang.org)

You should check what browser support you need. Companies often stick a long time with older browsers like IE6. Dart doesn't support older browsers very well.